# Tensorflow Image Translator (Pix2Pix)

Tags: python, image, tensorflow

I need some help with this TensorFlow project. I would like to reprogram something like Pix2Pix. I encountered some problems, especially when reading in images and defining the TensorFlow graph. But first I created a folder ("Source/"), in which there are many pictures of different sizes. The CNN is now to be trained to turn a".jpg" image into a".JPG" image. The "jpg" and "JPG" have the same height, width and depth(RGB). However, the "JPG" differs in its structure from the "jpg" (as it does in Pix2Pix). I think my problems arise during training and I have a "wrong" TensorFlow graph (one that should be improved). Here is my current code:

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.contrib.layers as lays

from random import shuffle

learnrate = 0.1
batch_size = 32

Source = "Source/"
files = []
for file in os.listdir(Source):
    if file.endswith(".jpg"):
        files.append(Source + file)
shuffle(files)

filenames = tf.constant(files)

safe_name = "test"

data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((filenames,filenames))

data = data.map(parse)
data = data.batch(batch_size)

def autoencoder(inputs):
    # encoder
    net = lays.conv2d(inputs, 3, [5, 5], stride=1, padding='SAME')
    net = lays.conv2d(net, 6, [5, 5], stride=2, padding='SAME')
    net = lays.conv2d(net, 12, [5, 5], stride=4, padding='SAME')
    # decoder
    net = lays.conv2d_transpose(net, 12, [5, 5], stride=4, padding='SAME')
    net = lays.conv2d_transpose(net, 6, [5, 5], stride=2, padding='SAME')
    net = lays.conv2d_transpose(net, 3, [5, 5], stride=1, padding='SAME', activation_fn=tf.nn.tanh)
    return net

print(files)

ae_inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, 480, 270, 3))
ae_outputs = autoencoder(ae_inputs)

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(ae_outputs - ae_inputs))
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learnrate).minimize(loss)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:

    saver = tf.train.Saver()

    for x in range(0, 1000):
        iterator = data.make_one_shot_iterator()
        images, labels = iterator.get_next()
        sess.run(init)
        sess.run([images, labels])

    file_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + "/data/" + str(safe_name) + ".ckpt"
    saver.save(sess, file_path)
    print("Safe File! - Training done!")

def parse(filename,filenames):
    image_string = tf.read_file(filename)
    image_decoded = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_string, channels=3)
    image = tf.cast(image_decoded, tf.float32)
    label_string = tf.read_file(filename.replace(".jpg", ".JPG"))
    label_decoded = tf.image.decode_jpeg(label_string, channels=3)
    label = tf.cast(label_decoded, tf.float32)
    return image, label
```

What can I do to improve my results? And what did I actually do wrong when defining the graph/the rest of the code? Is there perhaps a well understandable example where someone has programmed Pix2Pix in TensorFlow and in which you can also use your own images?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately, this question is pretty hard to understand, and probably a bit too open-ended. Can you further specify the reasoning behind assuming a "wrong" graph? What are the current outcomes and expected outcomes of the network? Reproducing this on our side may not be possible without the data set. If it just happens that you were expecting better performance, this might come down to a research matter, which is unfitting for this Q&A site.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer :)
By the "wrong" graph I mean that the graph is probably too small / actually wrongly defined, because the results are just an image with vertical red, green and blue stripes (all the same). In addition, the original "Pix2Pix" also uses a much larger network, but I don't know how to implement it. So what can I do to get a real result at all?

Comment: [link](https://github.com/affinelayer/pix2pix-tensorflow/blob/master/docs/tensorboard-graph.png)

Comment: You may wish to [edit] your question to include as many details as possible (comments are ephemeral and may be removed without warning). This includes sample data and decoded samples out of the auto-encoder. This is as far as I can suggest, I'm afraid.

Comment: Try to print the output of the autoencoder to see what the picture look like...

Comment: A good way to see the efficiency of the network is to print the losses of the discriminator and the generator. Post the pictures